# NSURL file extension addition etc

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I have received a URL from the savePanel sheet and I would like to do following:

- Check to see if it has an extension
- if it does, remove it
- add a custom extension
- if it does not, then add a custom extension

Any simple way to do this.. I tried something like following but it does not work

```
if ( [tmp pathExtension] != @"xxx" )
   path = [tmp stringByAppendingFormat:@"xxx"];
```

OK... A possible solution as follows

```
NSString *path;
NSURL *filepath;
fileurl = [sheet URL];
fileurl = [fileurl URLByDeletingPathExtension];
fileurl = [fileurl URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"yyy"];
path = [fileurl path];
```

Comment: Yes Vince.. thanks for your help. Both solutions work nicely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved using `NSString`'s methods. Note that for string comparison, you have to use `isEqualToString:`, not `==`, which tests for pointers equality.

About the extension use : `-(NSString *)pathExtension;`. To remove the extension use `-(NSString *)stringByDeletingPathExtension;`.

In all cases to add an extension, compose a new string using for example : `+(NSString *)stringWithFormat:`.

So :

```
NSString *finalString;
if([[tmp pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"xxx"]) {
    finalString = [tmp stringByDeletingPathExtension];
}
finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.yyy", finalString];
```

Comment: Another solution from a friend.... 

    NSString *path;
    NSURL *filepath;
    fileurl = [sheet URL];
    fileurl = [fileurl URLByDeletingPathExtension];
    fileurl = [fileurl URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"yyy"];
    path = [fileurl path];

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to the workable solution given on this same page by @user756245 but using different `NSString` methods:

```
NSString *finalString;
if([[tmp pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"xxx"]) {
    finalString = [tmp stringByDeletingPathExtension];
}

finalString = [finalString stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"yyy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update for Swift 4.1 using `URL`

```
// assuming you are building an URL from string
let url = URL(string: "file.abc")!
let finalUrl = url.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension("mp3")
let finalString = finalUrl.path // output "file.mp3"
```